# Converting string with decimal to float & int doesn't result in same amount

Tags: php

I have written the following PHP snippet to show some weird PHP behavior.

```
<?php
$amount = "9.95";
var_dump($amount); // string(4) "9.95" 
echo '<br />';

settype($amount, "float");
var_dump($amount); // float(9.95)
echo '<br />';

$amount = $amount * 100;
var_dump($amount); // float(995)
echo '<br />';

settype($amount, "int");
var_dump($amount); // int(994)
?>
```

I expected the last output to be 995, but instead the result is 994. Why is this happening?
Online snippet:
http://codepad.org/tpnxwm0W

Comment: Floats are not a precise data type. You can read more about it in [PHP's manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) and on [Why don't my numbers add up?](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Comment: This is not php specific. This problem happens on most (or maybe all) programming languages. It's because of the base 2 (binary).

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with the same issue in js: https://jsfiddle.net/cmkzr22w/. If you need precise numbers, don't use floats.